# joining multidimensional arrays by values

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

Hi I have a slight problem where I query mysql and retrieve a list of data to json encode and plot into a graph (e.g amount vs dates axis). However sql rightfully doesn't return dates of query data where there is no data. and so there are missing dates on the graph.

I have read on here some people bodge jobs of creating other tables  simply to fill in the blanks. This is not an option for me.

I have a solution that creates an array of all dates in the query.

Can someone suggest a means of zipping this to my multidimensional array of query results. hopefully by some means of a clever foreach.

Or is there an SQL function I am not sure about that can fill in the blank dates?

my query currently looks like:

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Date, SUM(call_answer) AS call_answer, SUM(call_busy) AS call_busy, SUM(call_noanswer) AS call_noanswer, SUM(call_notrec) as call_notrec
    FROM ( 
        SELECT * FROM ( 
            SELECT substring(dateCreated, 1,10) AS Date, COUNT(id) as call_answer, 0 as call_busy, 0 as call_noanswer, 0 as call_notrec
            FROM cdr 
            WHERE  (company = '8346767432431') AND (dateCreated >= '2012-10-16' ) AND (dateCreated <= '2012-11-16' )  AND dialStatus = 'NORMAL_CLEARING' GROUP BY Date ) 
            AS t_0 
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM ( 
            SELECT substring(dateCreated, 1,10) AS Date, 0 as call_answer, COUNT(id) as call_busy, 0 as call_noanswer, 0 as call_notrec
            FROM cdr 
            WHERE  (company = '8346767432431') AND (dateCreated >= '2012-10-16' ) AND (dateCreated <= '2012-11-16' )  AND dialStatus = 'USER_BUSY' GROUP BY Date )
            AS t_1
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM ( 
            SELECT substring(dateCreated, 1,10) AS Date, 0 as call_answer, 0 as call_busy, COUNT(id) as call_noanswer, 0 as call_notrec
            FROM cdr 
            WHERE  (company = '8346767432431') AND (dateCreated >= '2012-10-16' ) AND (dateCreated <= '2012-11-16' )  AND (dialStatus = 'ORIGINATOR_CANCEL' OR dialStatus = 'NO_USER_RESPONSE') GROUP BY Date )
            AS t_2
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM ( 
            SELECT substring(dateCreated, 1,10) AS Date, 0 as call_answer, 0 as call_busy, 0 as call_noanswer, COUNT(id) as call_notrec
            FROM cdr 
            WHERE  (company = '8346767432431') AND (dateCreated >= '2012-10-16' ) AND (dateCreated <= '2012-11-16' )  AND (dialStatus = 'UNALLOCATED_NUMBER' OR dialStatus = 'INVALID_NUMBER_FORMAT') GROUP BY Date )
            AS t_3

    )

    AS t_total
    GROUP BY Date;
```

So is already quite messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your SQL query using the fact that the result of a comparison in MySQL is a number; 0 for false and 1 for true. So you can sum comparisons to compute your counts.

```sql
SELECT DATE(dateCreated) AS `Date`,
 SUM(dialStatus = 'NORMAL_CLEARING') AS call_answer,
 SUM(dialStatus = 'USER_BUSY') AS call_busy,
 SUM(dialStatus = 'ORIGINATOR_CANCEL') AS call_noanswer,
 SUM(dialStatus = 'UNALLOCATED_NUMBER') AS call_notrec
FROM cdr 
WHERE company = '8346767432431'
  AND dateCreated BETWEEN '2012-10-16' AND '2012-11-16' -- = 11-16 0:00 !
GROUP BY DATE(dateCreated) ASC
```

Note that the end of your range, both in this query and in your original one, will implicitely assume a *time* of `0:00`. So you won't include that day, except for the very first second. You might need to asjust that.

As for the actual question of how to combine things: the above query generates dates in ascending order. So take your list of dates, and see whether the first item on that list equals the date of the next record. While this is not the case, insert a row of zeros into your result data and continue with the next date from your list, maintaining the current record from the query untouched.